# Non Self Adjoint ideal in C(D)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

I'm currently working on a problem that's asking me to give an example of a non self adjoint ideal of $C(D) = \{f: D \longrightarrow \mathbb{C} \: | \: \text{$f$ is continuous}\}$ with $||\cdot||_{\infty}$, and $D = \{z \in \mathbb{C} \: |\: |z| \leq 1\}$.

So far I've been trying to mess with holomorphicity, integration, compact supports, and  noninvertible functions.

My issue is that I keep yielding either a vector subspace which isn't self adjoint but not an ideal (like the collection of all holomorphic functions), or I get an ideal thats self adjoint (functions with compact support, functions whose integral over $D$ is $0$, maximal ideals of the form $M_y=\{f \in C(D) \: | \: f(y)=0\}$, etc).  I know that whatever ideal I choose, it can't be closed ofcourse.

I would be very appreciative of a $\textbf{small hint that points me in the right direction, not a full answer}$!

Comment: @QuantumSpace No, I'm just mentioning that C(D) is equipped with the usual sup norm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: Consider the identity function $z\in C(D)$ and the ideal $I:= C(D)z.$ Does it contain $\overline{z}$?

Comment: Ah okay, this is kind of what I had in mind with holomorphicity of the inclusion $z$ and $\overline{z}$, Thanks!